# Webscraping with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm beginner in coding and try to learn webscraping with selenium, I been working on a project to check with a dictionary how long it takes to crack a password with every single word.
So my code reads a .txt file that has a word on each line, then writes it to the bar and it would copy how long it would take to crack it.
The problem is that I cannot capture a part of the html code of the webpage and I need help.

This is my code

```
# This program run spanish dictionary and check how secure password there are

import random
import time
from selenium import webdriver

#Paste here Chromedriver path
CHROMEDRIVERPATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
#Paste here dictionary path in .txt format
dictionary = readFile("spanish_dictionary.txt")
date = str(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S"))

#read files
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVERPATH)

#webpage target
driver.get("https://www.security.org/how-secure-is-my-password/")
time.sleep(2)

#Label
writeFile("results_" + date + ".txt","word,time \n")
#File Content
for word in dictionary:
    bar = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
    bar.send_keys(word)
    bar.clear()
    timeToCrack = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hsimp"]/div[1]/div[3]/p[2]').get_attribute("class")
    result = word + "," + timeToCrack + "\n"
    writeFile("results_" + date + ".txt",result)
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.4,1.0))
```

This is html code of the page

```
<p class="result__text result__time">2 hundred microseconds</p>
```

I get this in output file:

```
word,time 
a,result__text result__time
aba,result__text result__time
abaá,result__text result__time
```

I want this:

```
word,time 
a,6 hundred picoseconds
aba,4 hundred nanoseconds
abaá,5 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
timeToCrack = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hsimp"]/div[1]/div[3]/p[2]').text
```

The Java equivalent is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="hsimp"]/div[1]/div[3]/p[2]").getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract and print the result you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.security.org/how-secure-is-my-password/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#password"))).send_keys("lordkoda")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.result p.result__text.result__time"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.security.org/how-secure-is-my-password/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']"))).send_keys("lordkoda")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='result']//p[@class='result__text result__time']"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  5 seconds
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```